# object not found error 404-codeigniter framework-xampp server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iam new to codeigniter framework and xampp server.Iam getting object not found error [image: controller folder welcome.php]

when i click on fivespecies it is displaying error message
[image]

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please add your code here. It would be helpful. @SanoojT it is in the image.

Comment: Also please add the ht access file if you have it

Comment: <IfModule authz_core_module>
   RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>[ht access]

Comment: due to the low reputation points i can't able to upload the images

Answer (score 0):

The welcome.php controller is your default, and when you don't declare a function name within the controller, it loads the index() function, so loading http://localhost/antimalarial/ loads the index function in your welcome controller.

However, if you want to load any other function within the welcome controller, you will need to provide the controller name **AND** the function name.

Your link should be http://localhost/antimalarial/welcome/fivespecies

Comment: where i should provide the controller name

Comment: As the link for the menu item. You're linking to: http://localhost/antimalarial/fivespecies when it should be http://localhost/antimalarial/welcome/fivespecies

Comment: Iam sorrry iam little bit slow in programming please tell me the procedure for the above link

Comment: In whatever view file contains your menu. It's most likely in application/views/header.php

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/fivespecies">five Species</a>         (I have edited like this)

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/fivespecies">five Species</a> (I have edited like this in header.php)

Comment: send me the facebook id i can clearly explain the issue with images

Answer (score 0):

Your might need to write your URL as: http://localhost/antimalarial/Welcome/fivespecies

If this link does not work, try this:
http://localhost/antimalarial/index.php/Welcome/fivespecies
This case is valid if you haven't already set the `.htaccess` file.

If you want to remove index.php from your url. Please download and add .htaccess file in your root directory. [Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/osycc0gqmkp0dt7/.htaccess?dl=0) to download the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to remove index.php

Comment: I have added the .htaccess file link in the answer. Download the file and paste it in your root directory.

Comment: You will find your project name "antimalarial" the .htaccess file.
whenever you design a new project just change the name in .htaccess file.